# Google Cast, requestSession with pre-selected Chromecast device

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

Using Google Cast, [Chrome API](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/) is it possible to cast to a pre-selected device after initialization without the manually input by the user via the Google Cast plugin?

The only thing I can find is joining sessions etc.

When running chrome.cast.requestSession the CEC (Consumer Electronics Control) is triggered on the TV and will power on. That is what I want to do without the manual input every time.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean to say you want to enable the CEC in your TV automatically using Cast?

Comment: I want the user to select a device once. And after that I want it to be 'automatic'. If it's possible to persist the device object and reuse it to avoid the manual input to select device